# go ethereum Approve success but unable to locate this TxnHash on bscscan

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, bscscan

I want to `Approve` some WBNB on bsc-chain(PancakeSwap) for swapping other token, currently the balance is "0.0008", the allowance is "0.0001", I want to swap all the WBNB so I need the allowance also be "0.0008"

So I did two steps:

1. `Approve(0)`
2. `Approve(0.0008)`

Both steps executes with no error, returns two transaction hash, but the hash doesn't exist on "bscscan.com/tx/0x....", it says "Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash"

I've been trying this for an hour, getting lots of hash that does not exist, and the balance/allowance doesn't change at all, still "0.0008"/"0.0001"

Here are some sample TxnHash:

```
0x32f4fa6addd0a2975c4456e77fa92b27ca6e4e54787e65de36e3c36802f77ebc
0x6d32e60dd06443fe835c0245fb7e5ce14880eaec8f5e2f5cd42242a58727616d
```

Why is that? My code:

```golang
    erc20_, e := erc20.NewErc20(WBNB_addr, rpc)
    session := &erc20.Erc20Session{
        Contract: erc20_,
        CallOpts: bind.CallOpts{
            Pending: true,
        },
        TransactOpts: bind.TransactOpts{
            From:     auth.From,
            Signer:   auth.Signer,
            GasLimit: uint64(Max_Approve_Gas_Limit),
        },
    }

    tx, e := session.Approve(PancakeSwap_addr, big.NewInt(0)) // 0 or 800000000000000 for 0.0008 WBNB
    if e != nil {
        return e
    }
    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, these hashes are all OK now, seems this is server issue for bscscan.com, not problem of the code.